# How to get rid of "col1" aliases from aggregate struct objects in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to aggregate json objects to json list - dynamically create struct objects that are created with various amount of fields. Each time I create an aggregate using the below snippet:

```
  batched = dataset.select(col(asteriskChar), row_number()
                       .over(Window.orderBy(order)).alias(rowNumAlias))
                       .withColumn(batchAlias, functions.ceil(col(rowNumAlias).divide(batchSize)))
                       .groupBy(col(batchAlias))  .agg(functions.collect_list(struct(structCol)).alias(batchedColAlias));
```

I would like to have object batches like below:

```
[
 {
      "id": 1,
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Thomas",
      "score": 88
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "first": "Anne",
      "last": "Jacobs",
      "score": 32
  }
]
```

, but I got below:

```
[
  {
    "col1": {
      "id": 1,
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Thomas",
      "score": 88
    }
  },
  {
    "col1": {
      "id": 2,
      "first": "Anne",
      "last": "Jacobs",
      "score": 32
    }
  }
]
```

How can I get rid of "col1" fields and make those jsons a single objects within an array? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you don't need the `struct` there:

```
.groupBy(col(batchAlias))
.agg(functions.collect_list(structCol).alias(batchedColAlias));
```